# Доступ к ресурсу внутри jar-файла

Tags: java, cmd, jar, resources

Стоит задача проверить валидность xml-файла, xsd-шник находится в /src/resource

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    if (args.length != 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal number of arguments");
    }

    // получаю файл .xsd 
    File xsd = new File(Application.class.getResource("/shapes.xsd").getFile());

    // получаю файл .xml 
    File xml = new File(args[0]);
    System.out.println(xmlValidate(xsd, xml));
}

// проверка на валидноть
public static boolean xmlValidate(File xsd, File xml) {
    try {
        SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI)
                .newSchema(new StreamSource(xsd))
                .newValidator()
                .validate(new StreamSource(xml));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

данный код прекрасно отрабатывает в IDEA, но при попытки запустить из консоли ("java -jar app.jar exmaple.xml") вылетает исключение:

```
    D:\Development\Java\workspace\sggroup>java -jar target/sggroup-1.0.jar shapes.xm
l
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema documen
t 'file:/D:/Development/Java/workspace/sggroup/file:/D:/Development/Java/workspa
ce/sggroup/target/sggroup-1.0.jar!/shapes.xsd', because 1) could not find the do
cument; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document i
s not <xsd:schema>.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAX
ParseException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unk
nown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(
Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(
Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.repo
rtSchemaErr(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.repo
rtSchemaError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getS
chemaDocument1(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getS
chemaDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.pars
eSchema(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema
(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGramma
r(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGramma
r(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.n
ewSchema(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
        at ru.sggroup.Application.xmlValidate(Application.java:24)
        at ru.sggroup.Application.main(Application.java:18)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Development\Java\workspace\sggroup\
file:\D:\Development\Java\workspace\sggroup\target\sggroup-1.0.jar!\shapes.xsd (
Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown So
urce)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrent
Entity(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineD
ocVersion(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.p
arse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.p
arse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse
(Unknown Source)
        ... 9 more
false
```

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.sggroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>sggroup</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>App</name>

    <properties>
        <java.min.version>1.7</java.min.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.min.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.min.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>ru.blabla.Application</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо файла используйте `InputStream` и получайте его через метод `getResourceAsStream`.